# Browser window closing as soon as we serve the electron app

Tags: angular, gtk, electron, gtk3

I am trying to run an electron app in dev mode.
I've cloned the project from github and did yarn install. When I serve the project using electron Builder after serving , I get the following error and the browser window is closing. This is happening after serving.
The error is as follows :

```
  Date: 2018-12-28T11:45:32.922Z
  Hash: 738b2924fa673b20d893
  Time: 20743ms
  chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 375 kB [initial] [rendered]
  chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 233 kB [initial] [rendered]
  chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.08 kB [entry] [rendered]
  chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 2.02 MB [initial] [rendered]
  chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 7.69 MB [initial] [rendered]
  ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
  npm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is /tmp/yarn--1545997508035-0.9439987616631156/node but npm is using /usr/bin/node itself. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.

  > Trackly@5.2.14 electron:serve-tsc 
  /home/agile/Desktop/yarnappnew/TimeTrackingApp_Electron-master 
  (2)/TimeTrackingApp_Electron-master
  > tsc -p tsconfig-serve.json

  Gtk-Message: 17:15:40.595: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
  PID 786 received SIGSEGV for address: 0x10
  /home/agile/Desktop/yarnappnew/TimeTrackingApp_Electron-master (2)/TimeTrackingApp_Electron-master/node_modules/segfault-handler/build/Release/segfault-handler.node(+0x2f27)[0x7f3552257f27]
  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x12890)[0x7f3565c65890]
  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(pthread_mutex_lock+0x0)[0x7f3565c5cfa0]
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6(XrmQGetResource+0x4a)[0x7f35622bbaaa]
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6(XGetDefault+0xd6)[0x7f3562297856]
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2(+0x9c81e)[0x7f356475581e]
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2(+0x9f270)[0x7f3564758270]
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2(cairo_surface_get_font_options+0x80)[0x7f3564728270]
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2(+0x2c362)[0x7f35646e5362]
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2(+0x2f464)[0x7f35646e8464]
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2(cairo_show_glyphs+0x24)[0x7f35646da344]
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0(+0x848b)[0x7f3564e5148b]
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0(+0x86bc)[0x7f3564e516bc]
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0(pango_renderer_draw_glyph_item+0x3e)[0x7f3564c2520e]
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0(pango_renderer_draw_layout_line+0x471)[0x7f3564c25ca1]
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0(pango_renderer_draw_layout+0x125)[0x7f3564c26075]
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0(+0x894a)[0x7f3564e5194a]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0(gtk_render_layout+0x18d)[0x7f35655f3d7d]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0(+0x219a81)[0x7f3565565a81]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0(+0x16ef2d)[0x7f35654baf2d]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0(+0x173b83)[0x7f35654bfb83]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0(+0x216c31)[0x7f3565562c31]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0(+0x382eab)[0x7f35656ceeab]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0(gtk_container_propagate_draw+0x1ea)[0x7f35654b5eea]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0(+0x169fd2)[0x7f35654b5fd2]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0(+0x11da34)[0x7f3565469a34]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0(+0x16ef2d)[0x7f35654baf2d]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0(+0x173b83)[0x7f35654bfb83]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0(+0x120341)[0x7f356546c341]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0(+0x382eab)[0x7f35656ceeab]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0(gtk_container_propagate_draw+0x1ea)[0x7f35654b5eea]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0(+0x169fd2)[0x7f35654b5fd2]
```

Node version is 8.14.0, Angular version is 6. OS is Ubuntu 18.04.1 .

I've searched a lot about this error but there are only few results and the results were not that useful. I dont even know what Gtk is and still I installed GTK if that would help.

Package.json

```
 "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "npm run postinstall:electron && npx electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "postinstall:web": "node postinstall-web",
    "postinstall:electron": "node postinstall",
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "npm run postinstall:electron && npm-run-all -p ng:serve electron:serve",
    "build": "npm run postinstall:electron && npm run electron:serve-tsc && ng build",
    "build:dev": "npm run build -- -c dev",
    "build:prod": "npm run build -- -c production",
    "ng:serve": "ng serve",
    "ng:serve:web": "npm run postinstall:web && ng serve -o",
    "electron:serve-tsc": "tsc -p tsconfig-serve.json",
    "electron:serve": "wait-on http-get://localhost:4200/ && npm run electron:serve-tsc && electron . --serve",
    "electron:local": "npm run build:prod && electron .",
    "electron:linux": "npm run build:prod && npx electron-builder build --linux",
    "electron:windows": "npm run build:prod && npx electron-builder build --windows",
    "electron:mac": "npm run build:prod && npx electron-builder build --mac",
    "test": "npm run postinstall:web && ng test",
    "e2e": "npm run postinstall:web && ng e2e",
    "version": "conventional-changelog -i CHANGELOG.md -s -r 0 && git add CHANGELOG.md"
  },
```

Please help. Thank you .